# CMS.DataEngine.LicenseException in Kentico

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, kentico

I am working on E-commerce project using Kentico 9, we used only Administration part of Kentico and designed our own front-end, we installed Kentico on our server and deployed our webservice that extracting data like product details and so on using Kentico APIs but we got the following exception in some cases that needs API to talk to database like:

```
 var custmerID = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserID(userID);
```

How ever it was working just fine in my PCs webservice thrown error when we deployed it on server:

License for feature 'Ecommerce' not found.

> CMS.DataEngine.LicenseException: License for feature 'Ecommerce' not found.
>      at CMS.LicenseProvider.LicenseHelperInternal.ReportLicenseError(String redirectUrl, String message)
>      at CMS.LicenseProvider.LicenseService.CheckLicense(FeatureEnum feature, String domain, Boolean throwError)
>      at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`3.GetObjectQuery(Boolean checkLicense)
>      at CMS.Ecommerce.CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserIDInternal(Int32 userId)
>      at SCTH.MAS.KNDAL.User.CheckifCustomerExist(Int32 userID, String siteName) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SCTH.MAS.KNDAL\SCTH.MAS.KNDAL\User.cs:line 39
>      at SCTH.MAS.KNDAL.User.CheckUserAvailabilityForBuying(String userEmail, String siteName) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SCTH.MAS.KNDAL\SCTH.MAS.KNDAL\User.cs:line 29
>      at SCTH.MAS.KNDAL.KenticoWebServices.CheckUserAvailabilityForBuying(String userEmail, String siteName) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SCTH.MAS.KNDAL\SCTH.MAS.KNDAL\KenticoWebServices.asmx.cs:line 90

Notice that:

- We used free license till now.
- Our site is multi-culture.
- We have one custom table in our application.
- Kentico in our production system will be on different server than DB server so if we Kentico has webfarm configuration we should configure it.

Can any one help us is it license issue or configuration issue or what?

Answer (score 1):

Diaa,

It appears you either do not have the license key installed yet, or there is something going on that it is not seeing the license key.  You must have at least a CMS Base license to use the ECommerce features.  If you have the license installed and are still getting this error, try going to your System settings in the admin console, dump the cache and restart the application.  It could be that it has just gotten stuck.

And when you say free version, do you mean you have been using a trial version?  If so, then if the trial license expired you would expect to get this error as well.

Even if you are calling something via the API, Kentico checks the licensing is correct during each call, so you need to make sure your licensing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "free" license key installed and you are trying to make calls which are not part of the free license then you could get this error.

Secondly, when you "installed" Kentico, if you modified the installation and didn't install the modules then there is no database representation or physical code files available so this could also cause your problem.

To make sure your calls or website see the new key, recycle the application pool for the website.  This will ensure there is no cached connection.